# Cookies in guard

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to use ngx-cookies for my auth system. But my cookies in my guards are empty, I don't know why ?

this is my service for set cookies :

```
setCookies(token: string, rememberMe: boolean = false) {
    const expires: Date = new Date();
    if(rememberMe) {
      expires.setDate(expires.getDate() + 7);
    }else {
      expires.setMinutes(expires.getMinutes() + 60);
    }
    const decodedToken = this.tokenService.decodeToken(token);
    this.cookieService.set('role', decodedToken['role'], expires);
    this.cookieService.set('firstName', decodedToken['firstName'], expires);
    this.cookieService.set('lastName', decodedToken['lastName'], expires);
    this.cookieService.set('email', decodedToken['email'], expires);
    this.cookieService.set('token', token, expires);
    console.log(this.cookieService.getAll());
  }
```

And this is my guards :

```
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private cookieService: CookieService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(): boolean {
    const role = this.cookieService.get('role');
    console.log(this.cookieService.getAll());

    if (role && role === 'admin') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Do you know why my console log in my service return all cookies like :
email: "dorian.chantrel@hotmail.fr"
firstName: "Dorian"
lastName: "Chantrel"
role: "admin"
token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImRvcmlhbi5jaGFudH"

And in my guard the console log return nothing

this is the format of expires : Tue Nov 14 2023 16:08:05 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale)